# Wordpress URL rewriting - part of URL after an existing page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite the following URLs like so (`%2F` is `/`):

```
/archives/JHW
 -> /archives?RefNo=JHW

/archives/JHW/1/1
 -> /archives?RefNo=JHW%2F1%2F1

/archives
 -> no redirect
```

The idea is to get the URLs looking nice, but then be able to grab the rest of the path with just `$_GET['RefNo']` from the `/archives` page, which already exists [as a page](http://grab.by/APRE). So far I've got:

```
RewriteRule ^archives/(.+)/? /index.php/archives/?RefNo=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But this doesn't seem to be working at all.

I've been adding it with this code inside my `functions.php` for my theme:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'archives/(.+)/?',
    'index.php/archives?RefNo=$1',
    'top'
);
```

and then gone to the `Permalinks` page in `/wp-admin` to make it regenerate the `.htaccess` file. When I look at the `.htaccess` the rule is in there, it just isn't kicking in like I'm expecting.

Where am I going wrong?

---

**Update**

My current `.htaccess` file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^archives/(.+)/? /index.php/archives/?RefNo=$1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Could you post your current Wordpress' htaccess ? Also, where is defined `/archives` since you said it was an existing page ?

Comment: It's literally [an existing page](http://grab.by/APRE) - I've updated the question with the current htaccess

Comment: Ok. But what about your rule ? You're trying to rewrite to `/index.php/archives/?RefNo=XXX` (passing by Wordpress) and in the beginning of your question you talked about `/archives?RefNo=XXX`. Which one is the one to use ?

Comment: I want the URL to be `/archives/JHW/1/1` but it to be handled as if it was `/archives?RefNo=JHW/1/1` (urlencoded). I've tried both with and without `index.php`, that's just whatever the last thing I tried was :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution which I've stumbled across is this (inside the theme's `functions.php`):

```
function archives_page_rewrites() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%RefNo%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^archives/(.*)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=archives&RefNo=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init', 'archives_page_rewrites');
```

I'm willing to believe there are other ways of doing it, and that this may or may not be the best solution. Feel free to up/down this based on if it's good/bad in terms of good-practice.